# How can I reload the following viewcontroller with a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview inside a viewcontroller. When pressing a button in the navigation bar I would like the table view to reload.

The view controller is called **FirstViewController**, the Tableview is called **listTableView** and the refresh button is called **refreshButton**

In the code below I have linked the refreshButton action but cannot seem to figure out which function to put inside it to trigger the refresh when pressed.

**The following is my code:**

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, FeedModelProtocol  {
    var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
    var selectedStock : StockModel = StockModel()
    let tableView = UITableView()
    @IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //set delegates and initialize FeedModel


        self.listTableView.delegate = self
        self.listTableView.dataSource = self

        let feedModel = FeedModel()
        feedModel.delegate = self
        feedModel.downloadItems()

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    @IBAction func reloadData(_ sender: Any) {


    }



    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {

        feedItems = items
        self.listTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of feed items
        return feedItems.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Retrieve cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "stockCell"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        myCell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        // Get the stock to be shown
        let item: StockModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! StockModel
        // Configure our cell title made up of name and price


        let titleStr = [item.customer].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "-")


        print(titleStr)
        // Get references to labels of cell
        myCell.textLabel!.text = titleStr

        return myCell
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you solved or not? You just need to call listTableView.reloadData() when Navigation Button trigger...

Comment: No this does not work.

Comment: @RelsonJames, where is your `refresh button` sector IBAction action, did hock up with your `storyboard` navigation bar of a refresh button for IBAction event trigger. i am talking with this `@IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIBarButtonItem!`

Comment: @RelsonJames Does the IBAction actually run when you tap the button?  (Use print statements or the debugger to verify.)

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes, print statements do work

Comment: OK, so what makes you believe that a table reload there doesn't work?  How about putting a print just before `return feedItems.count` to see if that executes after a tap?

Comment: Yes that also executes after a tap..there must be something else I am missing, when the app starts the table correctly reloads, but when I press the button it doesn't

Comment: If that executes, then the table **is** reloading!  The question now is: what do you expect to see that you're not seeing.

Comment: @PhillipMills Please take a look my updated post, the code I added shows how new information I added, I just though the data would reload itself when running reloadData()

Comment: @PhillipMills any thoughts as to what else I should try, I fairly new to swift and I appreciate your help

Comment: Does that mean that you don't *just* want to reload the table with existing data but also want to go to the server for new items?  If so, call `feedModel.downloadItems()`.

Comment: I tried this before, but I get the error unresolved identifier for feedModel

Comment: It only works properly when I do viewDidLoad()

Comment: right click on the bar button in storyboard and check if connection is set properly and it is set to the function you want

Comment: i dont see you using itemsdownloaded function which i think you are using for delegate and protocol

Comment: Move `let feedModel = FeedModel()` out of the function and make it an instance variable, **then** reference it wherever you need in the class.

Comment: Also, what's the point of `let tableView = UITableView()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `yourUITableView.reloadData()` for this. Check [Apple's Developer page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata) for more info.

Comment: No, this does not work for some reason. The code now says:     @IBAction func reloadData(_ sender: Any) {
        
        listTableView.reloadData()    }

Comment: Check it again, `@IBAction func reloadData(_:)` has nothing inside it.